# C# .NET 6.0 - exe only?

Tags: c#, .net, resources

Hey I switched from NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6.0

When I build my file it outputs the build.exe (130kb) and an build.dll (2.3mb).
So it looks like the exe is using the dll to run as the dll has the source code inside and the .exe doesn't.

Is it possible to build an .exe only without the dll?
I tried to use a Costura Fody an resource embedder but that didn't work.

Edit:
I was able to use the "publish" feature to create a self contained exe but the file size increased from 3mb to an 180mb exe... Is there any other method?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want a single file framework dependent deployment and not "self contained". This way you would not have to include all the framework file in your deployment package, instead the computer would have to have the framework already installed. To do this, change *deployment mode* in the deployment settings from **self contained** to **framework dependent**. See [Single file deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file)

You might also check out "[trimming](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/app-trimming-in-net-5/)" to remove unneeded dependencies, since this should significantly reduce the size of a self contained application.

Answer (score 2):

Your observation is right.

The `.exe` file of a .NET core app is only a stub loader. The actual code is in the `.dll` file. For the application project, you now have both an `application.dll` **and** an `application.exe`.

Unless you use any of the options you mentioned (deploy as single file), I don't think there's a way around this.

Comment: And if I want to start a 2nd instance of myself, how can I do that? Does changing the extension from `.dll` to `.exe`  of the return value of `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location` always work?

Comment: @BitLauncher Yes, that should work. However, I would probably use `Assembly.GetExecutionAssembly().Location + "MyApplication.exe"` but that's nitpicking.

Comment: Thanks, I used  `var entryAssemblyPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location;
var exePath = Path.ChangeExtension(entryAssemblyPath, "exe");` despite I cannot rely on it, because Microsoft could change it perhaps in future, or I do not know the documentation reassuring such convention being always true.

Comment: @BitLauncher I think this is safe to do, as it certainly won't break without you updating the runtime and rebuilding. Write an unit test, so you would notice a change.